Is there a Blender alternative for Maya's Smooth Mesh tool? Something that both subdivides and smoothes a mesh? (regular sub-d modifier is NOT it!)
I've been losing my mind over this for the past couple of days so please bear with me. I'm learning more about topology and am following a Maya-based course to do so. The principles are the same, but I am hitting a wall regarding a function Blender doesn't seem to be able to recreate.
The instructor rightfully says that you can't just add loop cuts paralell to ones that define the curve on curved meshes because these disrupt the flow and create wobble. Instead, he uses Maya's smooth mesh tool to BOTH subdivide the mesh AND smooth it out so it retains the original shape. This is the tool:

I'm working on an assignment that has students recreate shapes and add proper topology to them. Here's the basic result:

While this is correct (the triangle isn't disrupting the shading and it gets resolved through subdivision), I want to create a denser mesh to reduce pinching in the part where the redirection is. This is where the problems start.
If I select all the verteces and use rigt-click > subdivide, the faces either start to follow the cylinder's original, non-shade-smoothed form at smoothness 0 or the top becomes wobbly at smoothness 1.
Instead, applying a single sub-d modifier set to 1 and simple rather than Catmul-Clark does EXACTLY what I want - it subdivides the mesh while keeping its original look intact. The modifier HAS to be applied and the topology can be worked on again if you need smaller details:

HOWEVER, whatever I do to subdivide this mesh further results in these deformations! (disregard the rounded corners, I'm talking about the visible reinforced vertical lines that make the cylinder look like whatever the 20-sided equivalent of an octagon is called the denser the mesh is)
Catmull-Clark:

And it's EVEN WORSE if I use simple now:

Clearly these extra divisions aren't following the curve. How do I get them to follow the curve? Presumably the first subd wasn't following it either, so this just exacerbated the problem. How do I make it so that the original curve stays intact no matter how many subdivisions I need later?
I NEED to be able to both have that extra topology the applied first sub-d provides AND preview further subdivisions with equal smoothness. The Maya guy just uses his magic Mesh Smooth tool when he needs more topo and can then do whatever he wants while I'm stuck with a wobbly mess!
So, do you guys have any idea what I am doing wrong and what I can do to address this? An add-on maybe? I have machinetools and meshmachine if that helps.
Before you ask, the model isn't at fault - you can reproduce the problem on any regular cylinder. I have also tried every available setting in the subdivide operation's pop-up menu and the sub-d modifier.
Thank you.

You should have used "only" the catmul. Now you don't have a cylinder anymore and it will subdivide what you have: not a cylinder.

I see what you mean Daniel, and this does indeed seem to resolve the mesh curvature. Still, I'd like an option that doesn't lock me into Catmull-Clark's mushiness just yet. The best thing about the simple sub-d was keeping the sharpness of the original form while getting additional topo.

Can you link to a demo of the Maya tool? Just linking the tool’s logo isn’t really helpful.

I know this is far from an optimal solution, but a boring workaround: you can create edge creases to prevent the deformations where you want for the first subdivision. After you apply the modifier, you can remove the creases

There you go @TheLabCat: https://youtu.be/igeCjABWI7U

Also, here's a concrete example where he uses the smooth tool:
https://youtu.be/_bpsEd_5IW4?t=6081

"The best thing about the simple sub-d was keeping the sharpness of the original form while getting additional topo": well, if you only want more geometry without the Catmull-Clark smoothing and if you are planning on applying the modifier i.e. working destructively instead of keeping procedural subdivisions, then you can just as well simply select all in Edit Mode, right-click and choose Subdivide from the context menu.

It looks like Maya turns on smoothed normals when you use its "Smooth" tool, so it seems to be a combination of Blender's "Shade Smooth" setting and the Subdivision Surface modifier. Smoothed normals are where 3D software fakes the look of mesh being infinite-poly, by interpolating normals between faces when it shades them. Here's an example of a low-poly cylinder (no caps) with smoothed normals turned on:

If you ignore the top and bottom (clearly octagons), it looks round. This is because the normals are interpolated across the faces. For all images where normals are shown, cyan is the real face normals, pink is the interpolated aka smoothed normals between the real ones:

But, when you add a SubSurface modifier to the mesh with “simple” (which means no moving existing vertices, just subdivision), you’re adding extra breaks in those flat polygons, without geometrically smoothing them afterward, so the mesh remains just as (un-)circle-shaped:

Smoothed normals in 3D work by bending normals of faces to match each other at the face edges while being in their original orientations at the face centers, so subdividing the cylinder means that there’s a patch of faces for every original one face, and all their normals are pointing the same way.
Here is a top view of the cylinder with normals shown.
Before subdivision:

With subdivision:

Because of this cluster of unanimous faces, there’s no normals smoothing between them to be seen (normals smoothing of a face does not take more than its direct neighboring faces into account), and you'll only see smoothing between faces that are not coplanar (i.e. flat to each-other).
View of the cylinder with subdivision edges shown:

Hope this helps!
S.D.G.
